# How can I move items from an array from one position to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const elementeSelected = ["a", "b"];
const allElements = ["m", "s", "e", "r", "q", "d", "a", "b", "c"];

// result allElements = ["a", "b", "m", "s", "e", "r", "q", "d", "c"];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-lederberg-yji13f?file=/src/index.js:0-175

I tried to reorder the items form allElement. I want the items from elementeSelected to be move from their position in allElements to the first position.

Comment: please make an attempt before asking, [mcve]

Comment: I did something with sort, but it doesn't work

Comment: No, what I want is, if allElements contain elements from elementeSelected, to be moved in the first positions in allElements (like a reorder of them)

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat the arrays together and remove the ones that were already used. You can do that with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and with filter. The filter uses includes to check if it is duplicated.

```js
const elementeSelected = ["a", "b"];
const allElements = ["m", "s", "e", "r", "q", "d", "a", "b", "c"];

const result = [...elementeSelected, ...allElements.filter(n => !elementeSelected.includes(n))];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allelements = ["m", "s", "e", "r", "q", "d", "a", "b", "c"];
var x= 6;
var pos=0;
var temp=allelements[x];
var i;
for (i=x; i>=pos; i--)
    {
       allelements[i]=allelements[i-1];
    }
allelements[pos]=temp;

var y= 7;
var pos2=1

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
var temp2=allelements[y];
var i;
for (i=y; i>=pos2; i--)
    {
       allelements[i]=allelements[i-1];
    }
alllements[pos2]=temp2;
console.log(allelements);
```